# Activity not launching from Fragment: no error?

Tags: android

I have a listener set within a fragment for various buttons, one of which should be the logout returning the user to the MainActivity. For some reason however it does not seem to be doing anything onClick; no error, no activity launch. I don't see anything obvious wrong with my code, could anyone offer a suggestion as to why it may be seemingly inactive?

It is the last case in the switch statement.

```
 //this handles our button click event
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnHelp1:
                // Help message for title
                //First we instantiate the dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                //then set the strings for dialogtitle and message
                builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_help1)
                        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_help1);

                //set the OK button
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button, dismiss dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                //then we pop it on screen
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                break;

            case R.id.btnHelp2:
                // Help message for name
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder2.setMessage(R.string.dialog_help2)
                        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_help2);

                builder2.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button, dismiss dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog2 = builder2.create();
                dialog2.show();
                break;

            case R.id.btnHelp3:
                // Help message for surname
                AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder3.setMessage(R.string.dialog_help3)
                        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_help3);

                builder3.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button, dismiss dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog3 = builder3.create();
                dialog3.show();
                break;

            case R.id.btnHelp4:
                // Help message for other name
                AlertDialog.Builder builder4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder4.setMessage(R.string.dialog_help4)
                        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_help4);

                builder4.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button, dismiss dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog4 = builder4.create();
                dialog4.show();
                break;

            case R.id.btnHelp5:
                // Help message for name
                AlertDialog.Builder builder5 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder5.setMessage(R.string.dialog_help5)
                        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_help5);

                builder5.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button, dismiss dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog5 = builder5.create();
                dialog5.show();
                break;

            case R.id.btnSave1:
                // Save button onClick()
                //set input strings
                String title = inputTitle.getText().toString();
                String surname = inputSurname.getText().toString();
                String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                String other = inputOther.getText().toString();
                String mother = inputMother.getText().toString();

                //check they have been completed
                if (!title.isEmpty() &&
                        !surname.isEmpty() &&
                        !name.isEmpty() &&
                        !other.isEmpty() &&
                        !mother.isEmpty()) {
                    updateUserA(email, title, surname, name, other, mother);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.btnLog1:
                // logout user
                session.setLogin(false);

                db.deleteUsers();

                // Launching the main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would double check your id first. Then place logs in the case to see what happens. Maybe the database action is hanging?

Comment: Can you verify through your IDE if this case is even being hit? That would be the most likely culprit. Like @AedonEtLIRA stated - your db call might be cauding problems but you should see a stack trace or something.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I never added the button to the onCreateView...

Sorry guys, long day.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
getActivity().startActivity(...);
```

Also try to debug if the click even occurs, if not, my guess is that the ID is wrong or you forgot to set the listener or assigned it to the wrong view.

Answer (score 0):

Check the layout.xml of the fragment. Most chances it has a wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I never added the button to the onCreateView... Sorry guys, long day

Comment: Hahah. Get a cup of coffee